Showing maximum in DensityPlot
I have plotted a function as a density plot and I would like to add a line to show the maximum value for each A (vertical axis).
a = 0.1;
\[Mu] = 1;
d = 1;
g = 1;
g2 = 0.1;
z0 = 2;
f0 = 1;
om2[A0_, ar_] := 
  1/(2  (f0 + 
      3  A0  ar^-1  \[Mu])) (-2  a  (f0 + 3  A0  ar^-1  \[Mu]) + 
     ar^-1  (2  A0  z0 - (d + g2 + g  ar^-1)  (f0 + 
           3  A0  ar^-1  \[Mu])) + \[Sqrt](4  a^2  (f0 + 
           3  A0  ar^-1  \[Mu])^2 + 
        4  a  ar^-1  (d - g2 + g  ar^-1)  (f0 + 
           3  A0  ar^-1  \[Mu])^2 + 
        ar^-2  (4  A0^2  z0^2 + (d - g2 + g  ar^-1)^2  (f0 + 
              3  A0  ar^-1  \[Mu])^2)));
Show[DensityPlot[om2[A0, ar], {ar, 0.01, 10}, {A0, 0.1, 2}, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {ar, A}], 
 ContourPlot[om2[A0, ar], {ar, 0.01, 10}, {A0, 0.1, 2}, 
  ContourShading -> False]]

I have already plotted the contours but they don't give the maximum value of the colour for each A. I would appreciate it if someone could help.

If you make a Plot3D you will se that there is no maximum inside your domain. The max value is on a edge.

positive maximum (the most red) is not at an edge, it seems to be in a parabola on the top right @DanielHuber

If you try: Maximize[{om2[A0, ar], 0.01 <= ar <= 10, 0.1 <= A0 <= 2}, {ar, A0}] you will get: {0.672877, {ar -> 1.92789, A0 -> 2.}}. Therefore the max is on the edge.

Oh, I meant finding the maximum for different values of A—so a line instead of a point. Your code finds the global maximum, not the maximum for different As. @DanielHuber

Keep constants in symbolic form to keep numerics accurate:
a=1/10;\[Mu]=1;d=1;g=1;g2=1/10;z0=2;f0=1;

Define function that finds max for given value of A0:
max[A0_]:=NMaximize[om2[A0,ar],ar][[2,1,2]]

And now put everything you need but in a different way (note keep range of ar smaller, and I flipped the axis):
Show[
DensityPlot[om2[A0,ar],{A0,.01,2},{ar,0.01,5},
ColorFunction->"TemperatureMap",
PlotLegends->Automatic,FrameLabel->{A,ar},
PlotPoints->50,
MeshFunctions->{#3&},Mesh->15],
Plot[max[A0],{A0,1/10,2},PlotStyle->Directive[Blue,Thick,Dashed]]
]


Alternatively, another way:
max[A0_]:={#[[2,1,2]],A0,#[[1]]}&@NMaximize[om2[A0,ar],ar]
pts=ParallelTable[max[A0],{A0,.1,2,.01}];

Show[
Plot3D[om2[A0,ar],{ar,0.01,2},{A0,0.1,2},
ColorFunction->"TemperatureMap",
PlotLegends->Automatic,PlotPoints->50,MeshFunctions->{#3&},Mesh->15],
Graphics3D[Point[pts]]]



Thanks for helping out. I changed the parameters a bit and it gives a wrong output. Are there specific conditions for which your answer works? These are the set of parameters I used a = 1/10; [Mu] = 1; d = 0.1; g = 1; g2 = 1/10; z0 = 1; f0 = 1;
